# Easy way to assign values to an array in Verilog?

Tags: arrays, verilog

So I'm creating a large FIR filter in Verilog, it has 256 taps. So I need 256 coefficients. I want to try and make my code as modular as possible so I wonder if there's a way to create another external file to the FIR module which contains the values for the coefficients? Currently the only I know to assign values to an array in Verilog is like the following:

```
reg [15:0] datafile [8];

initial
begin
    datafile[0] = 32768;
    datafile[1] = 37045;
    datafile[2] = 41248;
    datafile[3] = 45307;
    datafile[4] = 49151;
    datafile[5] = 52715;
    datafile[6] = 55938;
    datafile[7] = 58764;
end
```

But when you have 256 values to assign this is a very long process manually organising the code, even with Find/Replace you can only do so much. What I want is the ability to assign values to arrays like you can in System Verilog:

```
reg [15:0] datafile [8] = '{8468,56472,56874,358,2564,8498,4513,9821};
```

I don't want to use System Verilog as it isn't as widely used. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need this only for simulation or do you need the array of constants to be synthesizable?

Comment: I want then to be synthesizable.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant as SystemVerilog is now widely used, and has features exactly to address this requirement

Answer (score -1):

If the values (coefficients) is saved in an external file (for example 'file.txt'), you can use system functions in simulation (`$fscanf`) to read the values from the file and wirte them on the `datafile` (`datafile` is an array).

In the following code I assumed that you have 256 values is saved in the  external file ('file.txt') and I tried to read the values 256 times from 'file.txt' and write them on the `datafile` :

```
module b(clk,reset);
    input clk;
    input reset;
    
    integer fileH; // file handler
    reg [15:0] datafile [0:255];
    reg [7:0] counter;
    
    initial begin
        fileH = $fopen ("file.txt", "r");
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset)
            counter <= 0;
        else begin
            $fscanf (fileH, "%d\n", datafile[counter]);
            counter <= counter + 1;
        end
    end 

endmodule
```

---

System functions are not synthesizable. It's for simulation. If you want to write a synthesizable code, I suggest the following way :

```
assign {datafile[0], datafile[1], ...} = {16'b0, 16'b0, ...};
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume this executes at compile time?

Comment: @George waller, I completed my answer with a synthesizable code.